# SSIS Incremental Load Performace

Tags: performance, ssis, lookup

I have a table with ~800k records and with ~100 fields.
The table has an ID field which is a unique NVACHAR (18) type.
The table has, also, a field called LastModifiedDate which holds the latest changes that were made.

I’m trying to perform an incremental load based on the following:

- Initial load of all data (happens once)
- Loading, based on LastModifiedDate, only recent changed/added records (~30k)
- Based on the key field (ID), performing INSERT/UPDATE on recent data to the existing data
  (*) assuming records are not deleted
  I’m trying to achieve this by doing the following steps:
- Truncate the temp table (which holds the recent data)
- Extracting the recent data and storing it in the temp table
- Extracting the data from the temp table
- Using Lookup with the following definitions:
  a.  Cache mode = Full Cache
  b.  Connection Type = OLE DB connection manager
  c.  No matching entries = Ignore failure
- Selecting ID from the final table and linking it to the ID field from temp table and giving the new filed an output alias LKP_ID
- Using Conditional Split and checking if ISNULL(LKP_ID) when true means INSERT and false means UPDATE
- INSERT means that that the data from temp table will be inserted to the final table and UPDATE means that an SQL UPDATE statement will be executed based on the temp table data

the final result is good BUT the run time is terrible. it takes ~30 minutes or so to complete

Comment: What are you loading the data from?

Comment: SQL server DB tables

Answer (score 0):

The way I would handle this is to use the LastModifiedDate in your source query to get the records from the source table that have changed since the last import.

Then I would import all of those records into an empty staging table on the destination database server.

Then I would execute a stored procedure to do the INSERT/UPDATE of the final destination table from the data in the staging table.   A stored procedure on the destination server will perform MUCH faster than using Lookups and Conditional Splits in SSIS.

Comment: I agree on performance.  If there is trouble using modified date based on timing, I have had success using where Id not In destination table.